# Useless horizontal scrollbar in Firefox with absolute positioned div with fixed height

Tags: html, css, firefox, overflow, css-position

I am trying to make a drop-down menu work on multiple web browsers. I am placing an absolute-positioned div below an input element, which contains a scrollable list containing items that can be selected.

On Firefox, if I give that div a height (e.x. to keep in inside the viewport) and if that causes the div to have a vertical scrollbar, this causes the div to also have a useless horizontal scrollbar. I want/expect the div to know how large it should be with the items + the vertical scrollbar so that it sizes itself correctly to have enough horizontal room to display all of the items and the vertical scrollbar, without needing a horizontal scrollbar.

On Edge browser, this example works with just showing a vertical scrollbar. On Firefox, the example shows both a vertical scrollbar and the unwanted horizontal scrollbar:

```html
<div style="position: absolute; height: 150px; overflow: auto;">
 <div>SomeText0</div>
 <div>SomeText1</div>
 <div>SomeText2</div>
 <div>SomeText3</div>
 <div>SomeText4</div>
 <div>SomeText5</div>
 <div>SomeText6</div>
 <div>SomeText7</div>
 <div>SomeText8</div>
 <div>SomeText9</div>
</div>
```

I do not know the width of the items in the list beforehand so I can't give the list a fixed width.

I would like to avoid adding padding to the div on Firefox because if the div does not have a vertical scrollbar, it will have useless extra space on the right. It also looks strange if the items don't extend to the full width of the div.

[image: Picture of Useless Scrollbar On Firefox]

Comment: Works fine on my Firefox. Vertical scrollbar only. My Firefox version is 124 running on macOS 14.4. However, you could try setting `overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto`.

Comment: I can confirm the example in the question has no horizontal scrollbar in Firefox on Linux. What system are you using? Have you tried in a window with all plugins disabled?

Comment: I am using Firefox 124.0.1 (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro, with no plugins turned on. I would like to keep overflow enabled in case of an actual overflow. It works on Edge for me, just not on Firefox. It's interesting it's working for you with the same Firefox version.